# Xaml intellisense not working after adding custom xmlns

Tags: .net, xaml, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

I'm stuck with following situation. I have WPF NET. 4.0 project in VS2012+Resharper with some number of xaml views and user controls. Project compiles and works just fine, but there is no XAML intellisense (or any other notifications that this is xaml file - for example no tooltip after hoovering over declared control). And this intellisense is breaking always when I include xmlns value for namespace declared within this project. For example:

`xmlns:conventers="clr-namespace:MyProject.Helpers.Conventers"`

will break all intellisense. Removing this line - will cause it to work again.

It only applies to namespace within the same project - when i reference external dll and use namespace from it - there is no problem.

Does anyone know if I'm missing something obvious?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok, i figured it out... It was easy, but irritating mistake. After adding `;assembly=` in the xmlns, intellisense started working again. In case anyone else will need it in future

`xmlns:conventers="clr-namespace:MyProject.Helpers.Conventers;assembly="`

works just fine.

Comment: The worst part is, when you *add the namespace using Intellisense*, it doesn't put that little bit on the end. So, in a way, Intellisense breaks itself!