# Visual Studio Exception from HRESULT: 0x860AC580

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010

Does anyone know why is this showing on my Visual Studio 2010 client whenever I'm editing some XAML in WPF?

Or where can I find what does the 0x8.. error means? Is there any place with most of the exception?

Comment: Not sure what that specific error code means, but you might want to simply try a *clean* followed by a fresh *build*. This sometimes resolves the problem (or might help pinpoint it a bit).

Comment: Does this happen for *every* XAML file or just a specific file?  If the file used to work OK, is it somehow corrupted? (review in text editor)

Comment: @Steve I could solve the problem by closing the file and re-open again. After that was working correctly.

Comment: @TimCavanaugh The file was working correctly until i changed a visibility from Visible="Hidden" to Visible="{Binding someproperty}". After that every thing that was ="" in xaml was making the exeption to show(i.e: Width="" - as soon as i entered the equal sign he would complain.)

Comment: Ah, there is a solution to the problem you just described! If Intellisense breaks, try adding `;assembly=` to the end of the `xmlns` string. This answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15131990/425871

Comment: If Steve's suggestion doesn't work for you would it be possible for you to include the actual XAML in your question so others can try it on their machine?