# XAML Intellisense Fails When Adding Project References

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012, telerik, intellisense

I have a WPF project that when I open a XAML file and start typing, Visual Studio briefly becomes unresponsive, and then Intellisense stops working on XAML files. However, it works just fine on C# files.

First I tried the suggestion here, but to no avail. [Xaml intellisense not working after adding custom xmlns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15121698/xaml-intellisense-not-working-after-adding-custom-xmlns)

I excluded almost all my files from the project, and commented out the rest, and still it didn't work. I removed a bunch of project references, and suddenly it worked. I believe I’ve narrowed it down to one of these culprits (all are version 2013.1.403.45):

```
Telerik.Windows.Controls
Telerik.Windows.Controls.Chart
Telerik.Windows.Controls.Navigation
Telerik.Windows.Data
```

Every time I add these, when I reopen the solution, a few errors appear in the Windows Event Log, such as:

```
Application: XDesProc.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException
```

I've had those DLLs in my project for ages, but it only stopped working yesterday. I checked out an older version from TFS (which previously worked), and Intellisense still fails. A colleague of mine checked out my project on his machine, and it failed. I can create other WPF projects and add those DLLs, and Intellisense works just fine (for now, at least). I've cleaned/rebuilt many times, but nothing seems to help.

My application seems to run normally, as does the rest of Visual Studio 2012; it is only the XAML Intellisense that stops working.

Help! I'm utterly and completely baffled. Not even sure if Telerik is the problem or a red herring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by updating the Telerik DLLs to a newer version. I had accidentally switched from the new version to the older ones a couple weeks ago, but I have no idea why it only stopped working now. I don't know what the underlying issue was... but it works now.

Comment: This may be due to the new assembly not being trusted. Please see this answer:- http://stackoverflow.com/a/26043022/1201038