# Does Not Exist in Current Context Error but Compiles Fine

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am running into what I consider a bit of an odd problem. I am receiving two "does not exist in current context" errors

```
Error   1   The name 'employeeDetails' does not exist in the current context    c:\users\kelly\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\insurance midam interface\insurance midam interface\mainwindow.xaml.cs 72  17  Insurance MidAm Interface
Error   2   The name 'searchBox' does not exist in the current context  c:\users\kelly\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\insurance midam interface\insurance midam interface\mainwindow.xaml.cs 80  34  Insurance MidAm Interface
```

However, the strange thing is, the project builds/compiles just fine and runs as it should. With that being said, due to this error, I am not getting IntelliSense on the objects which I would like to have.

I recently made extensive edits to the XAML, so I presume it has something to do with that as the errors did not appear before then (actually, 'employeeDetails' did not exist then, but 'searchBox' did). Grid and TextBox are obviously quite basic controls, so I do not see how it would be an error with my references or namespaces.

I would sincerely appreciate any help.

The relevant CS:

```
private void viewButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {


            DataRowView selectedValue = (DataRowView)employeeGrid.SelectedItem;
            MessageBox.Show(selectedValue.Row[0].ToString());

                employeeGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                employeeDetails.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;



        }

        private void searchBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            String currentText = searchBox.Text;
            ds.Tables["Employees"].DefaultView.RowFilter = "last like '" + currentText + "*'";
        }
    }
}
```

and the XAML (sorry about the length, but I am afraid that if I trim it, I may possibly be removing the trouble code):

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Insurance_MidAm_Interface" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="Insurance_MidAm_Interface.MainWindow"
        Title="View Employees" Height="700" Width="1000" Loaded="Window_Loaded" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowState="Maximized">

    <StackPanel Name="outerPanel">
        <Grid Visibility="Collapsed" Name="employeeDetails" >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="50"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
                <Label Name="labelEmpSSN" Content="SSN: "></Label> <Label Name="labelEmpName" Content="Name: "></Label>
                <Label Name="labelEmpAddress" Content="Address:"></Label>
                <Label Name="labelEmpBirth" Content="DOB: "></Label>
                <Label Name="labelEmpGender" Content="Gender"></Label>
                <Label Name="labelEmpInsurance" Content="Insurance: "></Label>
                <Label Name="labelEmpDependents" Content="Dependents: "></Label>
                <Label Name="labelEmpLocation" Content="Location: "></Label>
                <Label Name="labelEmpVision" Content="Vision: "></Label></StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
                <Label Name="labelReportDate" Content="Date: " />
                <Label Name="labelReportAction" Content="Action: " />                
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2">
                <Label Name="labelSpouseName" Content="Name: "></Label>
                    <Label Name="labelSpouseGender" Content="Gender: "></Label>
                <Label Name="labelSpouseSSN" Content="SSN: "></Label>
                <Label Name="labelSpouseBirth" Content="DOB: "></Label>
                <Label Name="labelSpouseAddress" Content="Address: "></Label>
                <Label Name="labelSpouseEmployed" Content="Employed by Company: "></Label>

            </StackPanel>
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="Children"></Label>
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="Life Beneficiaries"></Label>
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Content="Vision Dependents"></Label>

            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2">
                <Label Name="labelChildName1" Content="Name: "></Label>
                <Label Name="labelChildSSN1" Content="SSN: "></Label>
                <Label Name="labelChildGender1" Content="Gender: "></Label>
                <Label Name="labelChildBirth1" Content="DOB: "></Label>
                <Label Name="labelChildAddress1" Content="Address: "></Label>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Name="labelChildStep1" Content="Step:"></Label>
                    <Label Name="labelChildFost1" Content="Foster: "></Label></StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Name="labelChildHandicap1" Content="Handicap: "></Label>
                    <Label Name="labelChildStudent1" Content="Student: "></Label>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3">
                <Label Name="labelChildName2" Content="Name: "></Label>
                <Label Name="labelChildSSN2" Content="SSN: "></Label>
                <Label Name="labelChildGender2" Content="Gender: "></Label>
                <Label Name="labelChildBirth2" Content="DOB: "></Label>
                <Label Name="labelChildAddress2" Content="Address: "></Label>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Name="labelChildStep2" Content="Step:"></Label>
                    <Label Name="labelChildFost2" Content="Foster: "></Label>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Name="labelChildHandicap2" Content="Handicap: "></Label>
                    <Label Name="labelChildStudent2" Content="Student: "></Label>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4">
                <Label Name="labelChildName3" Content="Name: "></Label>
                <Label Name="labelChildSSN3" Content="SSN: "></Label>
                <Label Name="labelChildGender3" Content="Gender: "></Label>
                <Label Name="labelChildBirth3" Content="DOB: "></Label>
                <Label Name="labelChildAddress3" Content="Address: "></Label>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Name="labelChildStep3" Content="Step:"></Label>
                    <Label Name="labelChildFost3" Content="Foster: "></Label>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Name="labelChildHandicap3" Content="Handicap: "></Label>
                    <Label Name="labelChildStudent3" Content="Student: "></Label>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="5">
                <Label Name="labelChildName4" Content="Name: "></Label>
                <Label Name="labelChildSSN4" Content="SSN: "></Label>
                <Label Name="labelChildGender4" Content="Gender: "></Label>
                <Label Name="labelChildBirth4" Content="DOB: "></Label>
                <Label Name="labelChildAddress4" Content="Address: "></Label>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Name="labelChildStep4" Content="Step:"></Label>
                    <Label Name="labelChildFost4" Content="Foster: "></Label>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Name="labelChildHandicap4" Content="Handicap: "></Label>
                    <Label Name="labelChildStudent4" Content="Student: "></Label>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="6">
                <Label Name="labelChildName5" Content="Name: "></Label>
                <Label Name="labelChildSSN5" Content="SSN: "></Label>
                <Label Name="labelChildGender5" Content="Gender: "></Label>
                <Label Name="labelChildBirth5" Content="DOB: "></Label>
                <Label Name="labelChildAddress5" Content="Address: "></Label>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Name="labelChildStep5" Content="Step:"></Label>
                    <Label Name="labelChildFost5" Content="Foster: "></Label>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Name="labelChildHandicap5" Content="Handicap: "></Label>
                    <Label Name="labelChildStudent5" Content="Student: "></Label>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2">
                <Label Name="labelBeneficiaryName1" Content="Name: "></Label>
                <Label Name="labelBeneficiaryStatus1" Content="Status: "></Label>
                <Label Name="labelBeneficiarySSN1" Content="SSN: "></Label>
                <Label Name="labelBeneficiaryPercentage1" Content="Percentage: "></Label>
                <Label Name="labelBeneficiaryRelationship1" Content="Relationship"></Label>
            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3">
                <Label Name="labelBeneficiaryName2" Content="Name: "></Label>
                <Label Name="labelBeneficiaryStatus2" Content="Status: "></Label>
                <Label Name="labelBeneficiarySSN2" Content="SSN: "></Label>
                <Label Name="labelBeneficiaryPercentage2" Content="Percentage: "></Label>
                <Label Name="labelBeneficiaryRelationship2" Content="Relationship"></Label>
            </StackPanel>



            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4">
                <Label Name="labelBeneficiaryName3" Content="Name: "></Label>
                <Label Name="labelBeneficiaryStatus3" Content="Status: "></Label>
                <Label Name="labelBeneficiarySSN3" Content="SSN: "></Label>
                <Label Name="labelBeneficiaryPercentage3" Content="Percentage: "></Label>
                <Label Name="labelBeneficiaryRelationship3" Content="Relationship"></Label>
            </StackPanel>


            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5">
                <Label Name="labelBeneficiaryName4" Content="Name: "></Label>
                <Label Name="labelBeneficiaryStatus4" Content="Status: "></Label>
                <Label Name="labelBeneficiarySSN4" Content="SSN: "></Label>
                <Label Name="labelBeneficiaryPercentage4" Content="Percentage: "></Label>
                <Label Name="labelBeneficiaryRelationship4" Content="Relationship"></Label>
            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2">
                <Label Name="labelVisionName1" Content="Name: "></Label>
                <Label Name="labelVisonSSN1" Content="SSN: "></Label>
                <Label Name="labelVisionGender1" Content="Gender: "></Label>
                <Label Name="labelVisionBirth1" Content="DOB: "></Label>               

            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3">
                <Label Name="labelVisionName2" Content="Name: "></Label>
                <Label Name="labelVisonSSN2" Content="SSN: "></Label>
                <Label Name="labelVisionGender2" Content="Gender: "></Label>
                <Label Name="labelVisionBirth2" Content="DOB: "></Label>

            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="4">
                <Label Name="labelVisionName3" Content="Name: "></Label>
                <Label Name="labelVisonSSN3" Content="SSN: "></Label>
                <Label Name="labelVisionGender3" Content="Gender: "></Label>
                <Label Name="labelVisionBirth3" Content="DOB: "></Label>

            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="5">
                <Label Name="labelVisionName4" Content="Name: "></Label>
                <Label Name="labelVisonSSN4" Content="SSN: "></Label>
                <Label Name="labelVisionGender4" Content="Gender: "></Label>
                <Label Name="labelVisionBirth4" Content="DOB: "></Label>

            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="6">
                <Label Name="labelVisionName5" Content="Name: "></Label>
                <Label Name="labelVisonSSN5" Content="SSN: "></Label>
                <Label Name="labelVisionGender5" Content="Gender: "></Label>
                <Label Name="labelVisionBirth5" Content="DOB: "></Label>

            </StackPanel>

        </Grid>
        <StackPanel Name="gridPanel">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Content="Search (by last name):" Margin="10, 10"></Label>
            <TextBox Name="searchBox" Width="150" Margin="0,10" TextChanged="searchBox_TextChanged"></TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
        <DataGrid  AutoGenerateColumns="false" ItemsSource="{Binding}" x:Name="employeeGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
            <DataGrid.DataContext>
                <local:employee/>
            </DataGrid.DataContext>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="First" Binding="{Binding first}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last" Binding="{Binding last}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="SSN" Binding="{Binding ssn}"/>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Name="viewButton" Content="View Details" Click="viewButton_Click"></Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Employment Location" Binding="{Binding location}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Email" Binding="{Binding email}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Address" Binding="{Binding address}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Insurance" Binding="{Binding decision}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Vision" Binding="{Binding vision}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Dependents" Binding="{Binding dependents}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: I haven't looked through the code, but by chance have you tried Build > Clean Solution?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that, and unfortunately, it did not work. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Have you changed the namespace of your project?

Comment: Thanks for all the help and views. I still have no idea what when wrong; however,  closing and reopening the solution seems to have resolved it. Thanks!

Comment: So, WPF has it's own `iisreset` now? :P

Comment: Our team seems to have trouble with these types of issues sometimes as well. XAML, Vistual Studio, and .csproj files don't always seem to play nicely with each other. It causes ReSharper to flip its lid frequently as well.

Answer (score 1):

On top of cleaning the solution, you can check/empty the `obj\debug` folder. I might be wrong, but I think several files in there are used by the Visual Studio designer.

Also, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15121698/xaml-intellisense-not-working-after-adding-custom-xmlns), adding `;assembly=` at the end of your custom namespace declaration like this could solve the problem:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Insurance_MidAm_Interface;assembly="
```

Comment: I just tried that as well, and then cleaned/built again, and am still getting the errors. Thanks though!